# What's the purpose of my followers "focus"?

Tags: diablo-iii

With  level 18, you unlock a new item slot in your followers inventory:

[image]

However, neither the game nor much of goole makes any mention of this. What's the purpose of this focus?

Answer (score 5):

It is simply a follower-specific piece of equipment, to give them stats and bonuses, same as any other equippable item.

Templars have Relics, Scoundrels have Tokens, and Enchantresses, [like you've discovered](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/enchantress-focus/), have Focii.

Answer (score 3):

> Focuses are primarily highly symbolic personal effects. They serve to help channel unusual enchantments.<sup>[1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/enchantress-focus/)</sup>

They're "Follower Specials" equivalent to the [Scoundrel Tokens](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/scoundrel-token/) or [Templar Relics](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/templar-relic/)—an otherwise useless item that offers passive bonuses. The [Blizzard site](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/enchantress-focus/) has a list of usable focuses.